# Mac OS X Apache install not working 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I'm trying to setup an apache server with php and mysql on my Mac OS X.
For this I'm using [this tutorial](http://www.jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x/).

After folowing the directions I still get a **403 forbidden** error when I load the page.

These are the steps that I've done:

1. `apachectl start`
2. Edited `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` ([here is my full config file](http://pastebin.com/etL72f1g)) I uncommented the line `LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so` and the line `Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. After this I restarted apache with this command `apachectl restart`
4. I installed MySQL with `mysql-5.6.25-osx10.9-x86_64.dmg`
5. I clicked on preferences and started MySQL server
6. I did `export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH` because it said so in the tutorial
7. Ran these command because they were in the tutorial:

   ```
   cd /var
   mkdir mysql
   cd mysql
   ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock mysql.sock
   ```
8. I edited `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` to make a new virtual host ([here is my full config file](http://pastebin.com/GHfZ0ZqR))
9. Restarted apache again with `apachectl restart`
10. Added a line to my hosts file: `127.0.0.1 roy.local`
11. Flushed dns: `dscacheutil -flushcache`
12. Started a browser and typed in: `http//roy.local` and I get a 403 forbidden page

I' ve already tried to give my `/user/roy/websites` folder a `chmod` of 775 by doing these commands:

```
cd /user/roy
chmod 775 Websites
```

And then restarted apache again, this didn't do the trick. Please help me out. If you need more information I'm happy to do that. I can't figure this out myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you also upload the httpd log here?

Comment: your tutorial URL is dead ... please fix. Also, what version of OSX are you running with , php, etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your setting to this. you are using the old apache syntax.

```
<Directory "/Users/Roy/Websites">
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Just for testing purpose, change permission of the directory and files to 777.